# How to restrict resources to those owned by the current user

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have a parent object, which belongs to a user (in the spring-security sense).

I want to use all of the niceties of spring-data-rest, but without having to override a ton, modify queries etc. in order to filter by the current user.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Just to summarize, I want something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tasks", path="tasks")
public interface TaskRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Task, Long> {}
```

... where when I go to "/tasks" it shows me only the tasks that belong to the authenticated user. I do not want to have to use urls like "/users/foo/tasks" if I don't have to.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `@Override` the individual methods in order to secure the entity.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tasks", path="tasks")
public interface TaskRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Task, Long> {
    @PostAuthorize("returnObject.owner.username == principal.username")
    Task findOne(Long id);
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in controller layer If the parent object encapsulate user information, use `@PostAuthorize` annotation on web services methods ... hope it will help you

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.body.username == principal.username")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<ParentDTO> getParent(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {
   ...........
}
```